# Algorithm: find the missing element from 2 given arrays, second array is duplicate

Tags: algorithm

Find the missing element from the given 2 arrays, second array is duplicate.

Example:
array 1: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
array 2: [1,3,4,5,6,7]

I read about using hashmaps and other complex approaches, but I believe the best solution is:

1) Add all elements of array1 and array2 separately, such that we have sum1 and sum2, then the answer is |sum2 - sum1|

2) XOR all elements of array1 and array2 separately, such that we have xor1 and xor2. Here xor1 is always from the complete array. The missing element will be xor2 XOR xor1 (from XOR applications http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2983/XOR-tricks-for-RAID-data-protection)

Edit: arrays not sorted

Am I correct?

Comment: arrays are always sorted?

Comment: do the arrays always contain integers?

Comment: @Joni yes always integers

Comment: `I believe the best solution is`; `Am I correct?` Without a measure for quality/`best`, I don't see a way to tell. Then, I don't think you need to look at O(n) elements, which your approaches do. (Oh, and please specify whether the elements that are in the 2nd array are in the same order as in the 1st.)

Comment: @greybeard not in the same order. How would you do this without O(n)?

Comment: With the specification as sketchy as it still is, I wouldn't give it a lot of thought: notice that the example has the elements in identical order, and the question does not mention this need not be the case (or how to judge `best`). I read `sorted` to be something like _non-descending_. Either doing something with one element of one of the arras tells you something about other elements, or it doesn't. If not, any solution needs to use all elements.

Comment: @greybeard the context in which this questions are asked is meant to be ambiguous. I said its not sorted; and even if the example looks sorted, that means nothing about other cases. If it were sorted, however, you can use binary search looking for distance between middle node and right/left and keep tracing where the distance is not the same as in the complete array. If sorted, can be done in O(logN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your algorithm is correct, assuming the array contains integers. The proof easily follows from the fact that `x^x=0` [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) `x=x`. It even works in the case the array contains duplicates.

*Proof sketch.* Let A be an array of n integers and let B be a copy of A with one element removed. Define `xorA := A[0] ^ A[1] ^ ... ^ A[n-1]` and `xorB := B[0] ^ ... ^ B[n-2]`. Since each element, except the missing one, appears **even** number of times, `xorA ^ xorB` will equal the missing element which appears **odd** number of times---all others cancel out because `x^x=0`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I was able to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First answer may cause an integer overflow in case of very large numbers.

Second options is better from all aspects. In addition, 1st array does not have to be the containing one. You can start XOR'ing from the beginning of the first array until the last element of the second. You will end up with the unique element in union of both arrays. It costs for O(n) complexity.

Comment: I like this answer because its what an interviewer might be looking for

Comment: Thanks, actually I learned this when I was preparing for an interview :)

Answer (score 0):

I coded for filtering the missing numbers for arrays containing items that has more than one frequency .But time limit is exceeded for size 10^5.Any logic to reduce time complexity is appreciated.

// Missing numbers

```
// Write your code here
 public static List<Integer> missingNumbers(List<Integer> arr,List<Integer> brr){
Collections.sort(arr);
Collections.sort(brr);
Set<Integer> list = new HashSet<>();
for(int s:brr){
   if(arr.contains(s)){
       if(Collections.frequency(arr,s)!=Collections.frequency(brr,s)){
           list.add(s);
       }
   }
   else{
       list.add(s);
   }
}
ArrayList<Integer> list1= new ArrayList<>(list);
Collections.sort(list1);
return list1;
}
```